# Can Isabelle be used to draw inference trees?

Tags: isabelle

Using Isabelle/HOL (2021), one can generate diagrams for simple inference rules, e.g. as follows

```
text ‹
Writing \verb!@!\verb!{thm[mode=Rule] conjI}! produces
@{thm[mode=Rule] conjI}, even in the middle of a sentence.
›
```

Is it possible to use the same system to generate trees of inference rules such as the following (from [here](https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/natural_deduction_for_first_order_logic.html)):

[image]